# DockManager LoadFromStream not working

Tags: delphi, layout, docking

I'm creating 5 forms and docking them to a panel called DockTarget during run time using something like

```
procedure TManager.InitChild;
begin
    Child := TChildWindow.Create(Self);
    Child.ManualDock(DockTarget);
end;
```

after all five children are created and docked I'm calling

```
Settings.DockSettings.Seek(0,soBeginning);
DockTarget.DockManager.LoadFromStream(Settings.DockSettings);
```

but it doesn't seem to do anything, all children are dock and no matter what I do to the layout before closing the form it opens exactly the same as if `LoadFromStream` wasn't there.

Settings.DockSettings is a TMemoryStream Loaded from file when the settings are created earlier.

and onFormClose I have

```
DockTarget.DockManager.SaveToStream(Settings.DockSettings);
Settings.Save;
```

Any idea's why the layout isn't being restored? Or an alternative I could use for saving/loading a docked layout?

Comment: Have you set the stream position to the beginning of the stream before reading?

Comment: I hadn't previously but I have now and it still doesn't work.

Comment: You could need a Settings.DockSettings.Seek(0,soBeginning); before DockTarget.DockManager.SaveToStream(Settings.DockSettings);

Comment: That's fixed it. The memory stream still had the settings originally loaded the first time the screen was laid out. The settings I wanted to read were the second set of settings in the file. Caling Settings.DockSettings.Clear before saving solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply need to clear the in memory stream before saving, otherwise I ended up with 2 sets of Docking data of which only the first one was loaded.